# Admin login not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

so i'm having an issue with an "admin login" that i've been trying to make work. If you guys can check out my code to see what's going on, it would be very helpful. All of the names match what's in mysql. The error keeps coming up saying I don't have the correct username/password... but I do!

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])){    

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "dxhxxx", "tcqxxx");
if (!$con){
die("Cannot connect:" . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db("dxh6110",$con);

$userName = $_POST['username'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select * from Churchadmin where username='$userName' AND      password='$passWord'";
mysql_query($sql,$con);

if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){

    $_SESSION['username']=$userName;
    $_SESSION['password']=$passWord;
    //if all information is good you will go to the next page
    echo "<script>window.open('view_prayers.php','_self')</script>";

    }
    //if password or username is wrong this will give them an alert
    else{
    echo "<script>alert('Admin details are incorrect!')</script>";
    }

}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're mixing MySQL libraries with `mysqli_num_rows` use `mysql_num_rows`.

- Those different MySQL functions do not intermix with each other.

You also need to start the session if you haven't already.

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Make sure also that your form elements contain name attributes.

I.e.: `<input type="text" name="username">` etc.

Then this line:

```
mysql_query($sql,$con);

if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){
```

that should read as

```
$run = mysql_query($sql,$con);

if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
```

- There is no `$run` variable defined for it.
- Error reporting would have thrown you an Undefined variable run... notice.

You may also change

```
$run = mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

to

```
$run = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error($con));
```

- In order to see if your query failed.

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, in regards to SQL injection,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Okay, so I will make those changes for sql/sqli. Name attributes are correct, I was just about to edit my post to input my form. Oh, and totally forgot about starting the session.

Comment: @DLH I've made a few edits. You may want to reload my answer.

Comment: @DLH You're welcome. There are examples in the links I've given you and the web has many out there ;-) so, problem solved? Edit: you deleted your comment.

Comment: i've never quite understood SQL injection and what it does, or even how it looks. But I'm sure I can do some research and look it up. Do I need to change my sqli's to sql? like: if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) to if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)?

Comment: @DLH as outlined in my answer, yes `if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)` and not `if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)` - `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions do not mix together. Go over my answer again and reload the page.

Comment: @DLH silly me, I made a typo also lol I fixed it for the `mysql_num_rows`. Sorry about that.