# Form stopped submitting into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Okay, it was working before.... now all of a sudden it has stopped. i'm not sure why. The only thing i've added was a delete feature.. and after that it no longer submits. I can delete an entry though =D

php code for form

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");
if (!$con){
die("Cannot connect:" . mysql_error()); 
}

$Firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Prayer = $_POST['Prayer'];



//if there is no input these messages will come up//    
if($Firstname==''){
echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
exit();
}
if($Email==''){
echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email!')</script>";
exit(); 
}
if($Prayer==''){
echo "<script>alert('Please enter your prayer request!')</script>";
exit(); 
}


mysql_select_db("dxh6110",$con);

//if everything is good, information will be submitted to database
$sql = "INSERT INTO ChurchPrayer (Firstname, Email, Prayer) VALUES('$_POST[Firstname]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Prayer]')";



if(mysql_query($sql,$con)){

echo "<script>alert('Congratulations, You have successfully submitted your prayer requests. You will hear from us very soon!')</script>";


}

mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Oh, I'm aware that I should be using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection... but I'm not sure exactly what it is or what it looks like. I will definitely add them later, when I get further into my school project. Currently worried about the functionality..

not sure what else needs to be added... i'll add my delete.php

```
<?php session_start(); //starting the session?>
<?php
//connecting to database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","","dxh6110");

//defining variable
$delete_id = $_GET['del'];
//command to remove input from SQL DB
$query = "delete from ChurchPrayer where id='$delete_id'";

if(mysql_query($con,$query)){

echo "<script>window.open('view_prayers.php?deleted=User has been deleted!','_self')</script>";

}



?>
```

My admin log-in works, and when the admin logs in it brings them to a page which will allow them to view entries and delete entries made to the DB. Currently there are two, but when I try to add more requests.... they don't go to the DB. No errors are given when submit is clicked.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).
Was your server upgraded?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. You'll find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: `("localhost","dxh6110","tcqfoz7","dxh6110")` doesn't do what you think. Plus, `$_GET['del']` and `?deleted=User` inspect that. Those are the two things that stood out for me.

Comment: `Oh, I'm aware that I should be using SQL injection` Haha no you shouldn't be

Comment: then this `if(mysql_query($con,$query)){` the connection comes 2nd.

Comment: or should I have said I should be using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection? lol

Comment: "I will definitely add them later" ? Before or after someone hacks your account and destroys your project?

Comment: After @Strawberry. Definitely after.

Comment: @DLH You seem to misunderstand what sql injection is, it is not just bad guys trying to hack your server, it is also you or any good-willing user breaking your system simply by adding a `'` in a value. So if you are worried about the functionality, you should start with avoiding sql injection.

Comment: @DLH go read the links I provided, it isn't hard to implement.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: okay, I will work on the prepared statements then.... thanks

Comment: go over all my comments again and links I provided.

Comment: plus, how are you using this, as far as a link to delete? it doesn't appear to be in your question, besides `echo "<script>window.open('view_prayers.php?deleted=User has been deleted!','_self')</script>";`

Comment: @Fred it's just a delete link that the admin can press to remove the input. yeah and that window.open isn't popping up, but I don't really need it anyway.

Comment: is your delete link `?deleted=XXX` or `?del=XXX` ? `XXX` being an example.

Comment: ?deleted=xxx , should it be as ?del=xxx?

Comment: yepper roonie, should that be what you're using, you didn't post the method you're using to delete from. `$_GET['del']` needs to match the parameter in the `?parameter` in your method.

Comment: I'm going to have to ask my professor to help me out with the prepared statements. lol but thanks again Fred for all the help... it is appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76473/discussion-between-dlh-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx")` doesn't do what you think.

`mysql_connect()` takes 3 parameters, not 4. The fourth is for something else. Four parameters are what one would use with [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), but those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other, so don't use that connection method if you're going to use `mysql_` functions.

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Do as you did in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29922730/):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx");
if (!$con){
die("Cannot connect:" . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db("your_db",$con);
```

Then this `if(mysql_query($con,$query)){` the connection comes 2nd.

Plus, `$_GET['del']` and `?deleted=User` inspect that. Those are the two things that stood out for me.

If your delete link is `?deleted=XXX`, it needs to be `?del=XXX` - XXX being an example.

`$_GET['del']` needs to match the parameter in the `?parameter` in your method.

I.e.: `view_prayers.php?del=XXX` if `view_prayers.php` is the file you're using to delete with.

---

Plus, as mentioned in comments, this method is insecure.

It's best that you use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).